# Getting AttributeError when exporting Heatmap using qgis2web?

Tags: heat-map, qgis2web, attributeerror, qgsvectorlayer

I want to make a heatmap layer on my webgis.

[image]

using these options

[image]

but when i'm trying to export it using qgis2web i always get this error.

```
2019-06-21T10:15:53     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/Rizki Permana/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 323, in previewMap
              preview_file = self.createPreview()
              File "C:/Users/Rizki Permana/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 286, in createPreview
              dest_folder=utils.tempFolder()).index_file
              File "C:/Users/Rizki Permana/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\leafletWriter.py", line 100, in write
              folder=dest_folder)
              File "C:/Users/Rizki Permana/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\leafletWriter.py", line 268, in writeLeaflet
              useVT, useShapes, useOSMB)
              File "C:/Users/Rizki Permana/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\leafletLayerScripts.py", line 88, in writeVectorLayer
              new_obj = heatmapLayer(layer, safeLayerName, renderer)
              File "C:/Users/Rizki Permana/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\leafletLayerScripts.py", line 430, in heatmapLayer
              hmWeightId = layer.fieldNameIndex(hmWeight)
             AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'fieldNameIndex'
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Which versions of qgis2web and QGIS are you using?

Comment: @TomChadwin i'm using QGIS 3.6.3 NOOSA & qgis2web 3.7.0

Comment: I've not seen this error before, and can't recreate it. Could you open a new issue at https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues? You can upload your project and layer file there, which should allow us to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug in qgis2web which caused that error when "weight points by" was set. I've now fixed that in the master branch on the QGIS to web repo at https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web (fix is here: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/commit/2efe919378a2fb3077f697d977c4bdf23f0230bf). You can wait for the next release, or install directly from that master branch (instructions are on the repo).